# Zend Search Lucene Document - Conditional Searching

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-search-lucene

I have a CMS that I want to add search functionality to. There are items that I want to index, but want to exclude from the results conditionally.

For example, there is content that is in a member's only area that I want to include in the results if a member is logged in.

How can something like this be accomplished with Zend Search Lucene?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can add Subquery to query. You can use:

```
Zend_Search_Lucene_Search_Query_Boolean
```

or

```
Zend_Search_Lucene_Search_Query_Term
```

or

```
Zend_Search_Lucene_Search_Query_Range
```

refs: http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.search.lucene.query-language.html

Comment: So, my all my documents should have a boolean field that holds the "Members Only" status?  I would append the search with: `AND members_only:"false"`?